# HTML rendering incorrectly in Outlook 2016?

Tags: html, css, html-table, outlook, handlebars.js

I have created a simple `HTML` email template using `HandlebarsJS`.

I have set up the text and the table to be centered in the email.

However the table element is centred at the left side but on the right it spills to the right hand border of the Email.

This does **not** happen when I open the HTML file in `chrome` - only in `Outlook`.

How can I avoid this in Outlook?

**HTML relating to the table:**

```
    <div class="table">
    <table id="carTable" role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Car Number</th>
            <th>Group</th>
        </tr>
        <!-- {{#each cars}} -->
        <tr>
            <td>{{carNumber}}</td>
            <td>{{processGroup}}</td>
        </tr>
        <!--{{/each}} -->
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**CSS relating to table:**

```
    <style>
    #carTable tr, td, th {
   padding: 10px;
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 13px;
   font-weight: normal;
   font-stretch: normal;
   font-style: normal;
   line-height: 1.38;
   letter-spacing: normal;
   color: #333333;
   }

   #carTable{
   border: solid 1px #cccccc;
   }

   #carTable td,
   th {
   height: 30px;
   transition: all 0.3s;
   /* Simple transition for hover effect */
   }

   #carTable th {
   background: #DFDFDF;
   /* Darken header a bit */
   font-weight: bold;
   text-align: left
   }

   #carTable td {
   background: #FAFAFA;
   text-align: left
   }

   /* Cells in even rows (2,4,6...) are one color */
   #carTable tr:nth-child(even) td {
   background: #F1F1F1;
   }

   /* Cells in odd rows (1,3,5...) are another (excludes header cells)  */
   #carTable tr:nth-child(odd) td {
   background: #FEFEFE;
   }

   #carTable tr>:nth-child(1):not(th){
   font-weight: bold;
   color: #2d89ac;
   }
   </style>
```

**CodePen link with full HTML code:**
https://codepen.io/Java123999/pen/zYGBoPe

**Screenshot of issue, note table in line with paragraphs on left but not on right**

[image]

Comment: Can you please post your final code output and screenshots of the issue in Outlook and how it should look i.e. how it looks in Chrome?

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the issue now if you can look at it , thanks

Comment: From the screenshots, it simply looks like your columns are reducing in width as much as they can but with the number of columns you have and the font size, they can't reduce anymore than that and so the table runs past the email edge. I'm only speculating though. If you could post your code either directly in your answer or in a service like Codepen and provide the link, then we can debug the actual output and see what is happening on send.

Comment: Here is a link to codepen with the full HTML code: https://codepen.io/Java123999/pen/zYGBoPe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outlook uses Microsoft Word as a rendering engine. You have to play by Outlook's rules. Use old school HTML with tables and include styles inline where possible. To quickly test in Outlook, assuming you have access to it, try sending yourself an HTML email. I don't know what version you're using, but a quick search for "outlook send html email" should provide good results.

Comment: Thanks. I am using 2016 edition - should I not use CSS styles then?

Comment: @java12399900 It's not just about what you are using, but also your users. HTML emails should be kept as simple a possible. Variation between email clients is immense. Complex CSS rules like `tr>:nth-child(1):not(th)` will not be well supported by email clients.

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the issue now if you can look at it. thanks

Comment: Here is a link to codepen with the full HTML code: https://codepen.io/Java123999/pen/zYGBoPe

Comment: Microsoft has wasted so many hours and frustrated so many people with this stupid decision to not follow the standards.